# Mover dados de um formulario

Tags: php

Boa tarde, sou novo aqui e também um novo "desenvolvedor, programador".

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Como eu faço para mover uma informação que foi registrada através de um formulário, foi para um banco de dados e uma pagina de cadastro, para uma outra página especifica?

**Por ex:**

Por exemplo, os dados do pacientes são coletados na triagem, inseridos em uma banco de dados e salvos em uma pagina de pacientes triados. Depois, esse mesmo paciente triado pode ter algumas informações alteradas após editar. Eu queria que após todo o procedimento, remover esse paciente da pagina triados (sem perder seu banco de dados) e move-lo para uma outra pagina.

COLOQUEI EM ANEXO UMA IMAGEM ILUSTRATIVA DO QUE EU QUERIA NO PAINT MESMO KKK

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBRIGADO GALERA!

Comment: Opa. Primeiramente aqui não é um fórum :) Não sei como está seu banco de dados, mas imagino que se o paciente está na triagem, já passou por essa etapa, está sendo atendido ou já teve o atendimento concluído são um campo tipo no seu banco né? Se esse for o caso, só fazer a consulta na página seguinte com os filtros necessários.

Comment: Desculpe por colocar forum, já apaguei. Por exemplo, os dados do pacientes são coletados na triagem, inseridos em uma banco de dados e salvos  em uma pagina de pacientes triados. Depois, esse mesmo paciente triado pode ter algumas informações alteradas após editar. Eu queria que após todo o procedimento, remover esse paciente da pagina triados (sem perder seu banco de dados, e move-lo para uma outra pagina).

Comment: Expliquei melhor o que eu disse no comentário em uma resposta abaixo.

Comment: A lógica pode ser esta mesmo que o @CaioRios falou na resposta. O resto depende do banco de dados, e independente do banco, você tem que aprender o CRUD. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer o que você quer, é exatamente o que eu falei nos comentários, mas vou explicar melhor:

- Crie um campo `status`, por exemplo, no seu banco de dados para seus pacientes.
- Quando você inserir um novo paciente no banco, passe com padrão status 1 (em triagem).
- Quando a triagem for concluída você passa pro status 2 (fora de triagem).

Dessa forma, na página de triados você lista apenas os pacientes vindos do banco com status 1. Na página de pacientes na outra página, você lista apenas os pacientes vindos do banco com status 2.

Pra "passar" o paciente de uma página pra outra, você cria uma função que vai setar o status do paciente para 2 (fora de triagem).

E por fim, se quiser criar uma função para "passar" o paciente de volta pra triagem, faça uma função que mude o status do paciente de volta para 1 (em triagem).

Comment: Muito obrigado, me deu um norte sobre o assunto. Agora vou buscar como criar essa tal função.